# function to print the contents of a text file

Tags: c, file, pointers, file-pointer

here's the code i wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Print_File(FILE *f)
{

    fopen("f", "r");
    char s = fgetc(f);
    while (s != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", s);
        s = fgetc(f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main(void)
{

    FILE *ptr = fopen("info.txt", "a");
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Invalid Input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * 101);
    printf("One entry cannot be more than 100 characters long!\n");
    printf("Enter your text here - ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", c);
    fprintf(ptr, "%s\n", c);
    fclose(ptr);
    Print_File(ptr);
    free(c);
}
```

After Executing the program on command line, when i manually open the file, it is updated alright!
But the file is not printed! Did I write the Print_File() function wrong?

Comment: `char s = fgetc(f);` --> `int s = fgetc(f);` you want an `int` to catch `EOF`

Comment: What do you think does `fopen("f", "r");` do?

Comment: You pass in a pointer to a file that has just been closed. Better pass in a file name, use that to open a file in a local `FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");`, check for a possible error, then print the contents as you've done (but obey Danel's advice above).

Comment: Or open and validate your file is open for reading in `main()` and then pass the open `FILE *` parameter to `Print_File` (if you can't open and validate your file is open in `main()`  there is no reason to make the function call.) As you are doing, you can just delete `fopen("f", "r");` from your function -- it is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the manual page for `fopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3p.html). It takes a file name as first argument, and it *returns* a `FILE *`. What you are doing is wrong.

You should change this:

```
fopen("f", "r");
```

To this:

```
FILE *f;

f = fopen("file-name-here", "r");
if (f == NULL) {
    puts("Error opening file!");
    exit(1);
}
```

Secondly, passing `ptr`, which is a closed file, to the function, is useless. Either open it *before* calling the function (and at that point do not use `fopen()` inside it) or just declare the function as taking no arguments and open it inside.

Option 1:

```
void Print_File(FILE *f)
{
    // ... use already opened file ...
}


// Then in main:

ptr = fopen("file-name-here", "r");
if (ptr == NULL) {
    puts("Error opening file!");
    exit(1);
}
Print_File(ptr);
```

Option 2:

```
void Print_File(void) // void == takes no arguments
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("file-name-here", "r");
    // ...
}

// Then in main:
Print_File();
```

Lastly, `fgetc()` returns an `int`. You need to use an `int` variable to hold the result, or you won't be able to distinguish between a valid character and `EOF`:

```
int s = fgetc(f);
while (s != EOF)
{
    // ...
```

---

Complete working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Print_File(FILE *f)
{

    int s = fgetc(f);

    while (s != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", s);
        s = fgetc(f);
    }

    fclose(f);
}

int main(void)
{

    FILE *ptr = fopen("info.txt", "a");
    if(ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file for writing.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * 101);
    if (c == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("One entry cannot be more than 100 characters long!\n");
    printf("Enter your text here - ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", c);
    fprintf(ptr, "%s\n", c);
    fclose(ptr);

    ptr = fopen("info.txt", "r");
    if(ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file for reading.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Print_File(ptr);
    free(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc prog.c -o prog
$ ./prog
One entry cannot be more than 100 characters long!
Enter your text here - HELLO WORLD
HELLO WORLD
$ ./prog
One entry cannot be more than 100 characters long!
Enter your text here - HELLO WORLD AGAIN
HELLO WORLD
HELLO WORLD AGAIN
```

Comment: @AbhigyaShridhar works fine for me. Take a look at the complete code I added to my answer.

Comment: ok Thanks, i got it! i'll have to use fopen() twice. If i use it just once, than the first character s gets will be '\0' where fprintf() ended!